# trouble figuring out why my css won't show up in my chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to html/css. In an example i was following along I couldn't quite figure out why my css wouldn't show up in my browser. I checked the code over and over again, but it is formatted the exact same way as in the example. Just wondering if there was something i may have overlooked. Thank you for your help !

```
<html>
<title>Starbuzz Coffee</title>
<style type=“text/css”>
body{
background-color: #d2b48c;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 20%; 
border: 2px dotted black; 
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
font-family: sans-serif; 
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You've never opened the `<head>`, for starters.

Answer (score 2):

you need a `<body></body>` also open `<head>` before closing it (`</head>`) so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Starbuzz Coffee</title>
    <style type=“text/css”>
      body{
        background-color: #d2b48c;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%; 
        border: 2px dotted black; 
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
        font-family: sans-serif; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```